# Conditionality principle P(X=T-1)=P(X=T+1)

Tags: probability

In class we were discussing the conditionality principle and the professor used the example in page 3 of the following link:
http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~brani/isyebayes/bank/handout2.pdf

$P_\theta (X=\theta + 1)=P_\theta (X=\theta - 1)=1/2$

On the basis of two observations $X_1,X_2$.

1) We can claim that $X_1\neq X_2$, and by such: 
$X_1+X_2=\theta+1 + \theta-1=2\theta$, this implies that $\theta=\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$.

2) The other possibility is that $X_1=X_2$, prompts me to do the same, but I have two different options:

$X_1+X_2=2X_1=2(\theta+1)$ which implies that $\theta=X_1-1$
However, I could do the same but use the other value of $X_2$ and get:
$\theta=X_2+1$.

Using the first two equivalencies of $\theta$ I define the function:
$\delta= \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$ when $X_1\neq X_2$  AND
$\delta=X_1-1$ when $X_1= X_2$

After that, it says that $P(\delta(X_1,X_2)=\theta)=0.75$
In class we expanded further this probability:
$P(\delta(X_1,X_2)=\theta)=P(\delta(X_1,X_2)=\theta, X_1=X_2) +P(\delta(X_1,X_2)=\theta, X_1\neq X_2)$
$=P(X-1=\theta,X_1=X_2)+P(\theta=\theta, X_1!=X_2)= \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=0.75$

I don't understand this last part, why is the first probability equal to $\frac14$ and the other one equal to $\frac12$. Would someone care to make a detailed explanation?

Thank you!

Comment: I have attempted to fix up some of your mathematics (mostly formatting, the odd typo). Please check it says what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three out of four dentists will consider the following array:
$$\begin{array} 
\ \Pr & X_1 & X_2 & \delta(X_1,X_2)\\
\frac 14 &\theta+1 & \theta+1 & X_1-1 =\theta\\
\frac 14 &\theta+1 & \theta-1 & \frac{X_1+X_2}{2} = \theta\\
\frac 14 &\theta-1 & \theta+1 & \frac{X_1+X_2}{2} = \theta\\
\frac 14 &\theta-1 & \theta-1 & X_1-1 =\theta-2\\
\end{array}$$
and arrive at the conclusion that the probability that the
decision rule returns $\theta$ as the answer is $\frac 34$,
but your mileage may vary.